# cell.imageView image won't load with UIImageView category

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a `UIImageView` category which hold the method below. The problem is that the image is not loaded, only after I scroll the table and the cell reload by the `UITableView`. Also when I print the self.superview I get nil, probably because the `UIImageView` is not just added as subview to the cell.

```
- (void)imageAsynchronousRequestWithURL:(NSURL*)imageURL completion:(CompletionBlock)complete
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:imageURL];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

                               UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
                               self.image = image;

                               NSLog(@"%@", self);
                               NSLog(@"%@", self.superview);
                               NSLog(@"%@", self.superview.superview);

                               [self setNeedsLayout];
                               [self setNeedsDisplay];

                               if (complete) {
                                   complete(image, error);
                               }

                           }];
}
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to set an image to `UITableViewCell` `imageView` before the cell is loaded. The only way is to create a `subview` on top of the `Cell` and then initialize this `UIImageView`

Answer (score 0):

If `self.superview` is `nil` it's because you didn't add this view as a subview of another view. To do this you have to call:

```
[cell addSubview:myImageView];
```

That said, your code has a number of multithreading bugs in it. If you scroll quickly, images will end up in the wrong cells. You also don't provide a way to cancel unfinished operations if the user scrolls the cell off the screen.

You might want to just replace your code with [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), or at least compare their source code to yours.

Comment: But it's not just a UIImageView, it's the cell's default UIImageView called cell.imageView.